# Выгрузить базу с сайта

Tags: php, html

Есть сайт, на котором (в одном из каталогов) в поле поиска можно вводить числа (для простоты эксперимента). Если номер есть в базе - выводится страница с определенными данными. Если номера нет - сообщение об ошибке.

Всего примерно 250-300 тысяч страниц есть в базе. Требуется написать алгоритм, который бы перебирал номера и выгружал информацию в базу (например, в csv файл). Капча или какая-то  другая защита от машинных запросов не обнаружена. Каждая страница имеет URL вида \Member\XXX (XXX - числовой номер).

Я никогда этим не занимался. Пока гугление предлагает сначала выгрузить весь интересующий каталог на локальную машину (через HTTrack), а затем парсить каждую страницу на предмет интересующей меня информации. Может кто-то подсказать, в правильном ли я направлении думаю или есть какие-то более эффективные способы получения данной информации?

Апдейт от 24.11.15:

Пока пришел к тому, чтобы скачивать конкретные страницы с помощью:

```
<?php
$limit = 10; 
 for($i = 1; $i <= $limit; $i++)
{
    $html = file_get_contents('http://site.ru/Member/Detail/' . $i); 
    $handle = fopen("$i.html", 'a+');
    fwrite($handle, $html);   
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Можно как-то загружать их не в проектную папку, а в некий подкаталог? Если сделать поиск и сохранение интересующей информации в файл внутри цикла, ничего страшного не произойдет? Нормально будут обработаны 300к страниц?

2) В процессе парсинга столкнулся с тем, что на месте email адреса есть куча левых ссылок, и правильный адрес "спрятан" между ними с помощью CSS-правил. Каждый раз - на разном месте. (Надеюсь, правильно объяснил). Как это можно обойти? Какая вообще есть литература по продвинутому парсингу?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что лучше все-таки выкачать на локалку, а уже потом ее парсить.

Объясню.
Однозначно придется проходить по 300тыс страниц. Это не обсуждается... тут все ясно. В любом случае надо будет "зайти" на страницу и считать ее исходник.
А вот дальше либо сохранять на локалку; либо парсить, анализировать, загонять в CSV и "забывать" о ней.

**Во-первых**, и самое главное, процесс отладки парсинга. Сколько раз придется запускать код парсинга страницы, пока добьешься правильного результата? Несчетное количество раз. Если не держать на локалке, то это будет постоянные веб-траффик, постоянные запросы, задержки (в зависимости от скорости инета и ответа сервера)... Да и потом, как Qwertiy написал, могут просто IP забанить.
Ничего из этого не станет проблемой, если идет связь по локалке.

**Во-вторых**, поскольку каждая страница будет представлять из себя `.html` файл на локалке, то ими можно манипулировать. Например, код парсинга делает, что нужно, сохраняет в CSV, что нашел, а потом берет исходный `.html` и переносит в другую папку с именем `сделано`.
Так будет проще отследить работу парсинга после отладки, когда запуститься в полную обработку. Также, если где-то в середине какой-то сбой, или один из файлов ошибочен, не надо будет прогонять уже те, что обработаны.

Ну и **в-третьих**, поскольку все на локалке, можно хоть в транспорте скрипт отлаживать и запускать :) Все-таки 300 тыщ записей за 5 минут не пройдут :)

Вообщем мой совет - **скачивать на локалку и с нее парсить**.

Comment: По поводу этого у меня в ответе говорилось "Можешь сохранять или не сохранять по необходимости". Я против не такого скачивания, а использования специфического софта для скачивания. Т. е. надо тебе 300К страниц, а ты запускаешь утилиту для скачивания сайта, которая кроме них скачает ещё в несколько раз больше, которые тебе и не нужны, плюс все скрипты и картинки. А зачем, если можно самому выкачать только то, что требуется?

Comment: Можете дать ссылку на примеры/может документацию по описанному процессу? Я никогда не парсил чего-то более одной страницы. Моменты, которые мне не совсем понятны: 0) Выгрузка информации на локальную машину. HTTrack подойдет или можно как-то эффективнее? 1) парсинг и переход от одной страницы к другой. (Подразумеваю наличие алгоритма перебора) 2) Сохранение\дополнение интересующей информации в единый csv файл

Comment: 0) поскольку у Вас готовый список URL `\Member\XXX` и скачать надо только их без зависимых страниц, то HTTrack или Teleport Вам не подойдут. Они скачивают сайты полностью. Лучше написать php скрипт, который пройдется по все URL и скачает их (посмотрите доки по `file_get_contents()`). 1) Переход между страниц Вас не должен волновать. Все скачанные страницы будут лежать на локалке в одной папке - просто брать их по одной, и парсить. 2) Парсинг и сохраение - это по заданию. Вам понадобятся знания регулярных выражений и работас функциями файловой системы типа `fputcsv()`..

Comment: насчет доков тут вряд ли есть что-то конкретное. Обычно народ скачивает определенные страницы под определенные нужды, так что доков немного. каждый пишет под себя. В общих чертах: берет URL, используя `file_get__contents()` забираете его содержимое, с помощью `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, `fclose()` сохраняете на локалке. Переходите к следуюшему URL и все сначала...

Comment: Спасибо. Завтра разберусь в том, что вы предложили. Сразу вопрос возникает, как в PHP реализовать цикл перебора значения в ссылке?    `\Member\XXX`    Здесь XXX заменить на некий параметр и перебором его от 1 до ~300k создать соответствующие каждому значению локальные копии HTML.

Comment: если номера пользователей последовательные, то простой `for()` вполне подойдет.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз. В принципе, дело пошло. Теперь вопрос непосредственно в парсинге. Правильный email в HTML-файле спрятан среди кучи ненужных элементов, при этом в начале страницы задано CSS-правило. У вас нет примера парсинга "сложных" страниц?

Comment: Рад. Парсинг - это всегда интересно :) Это достойно отдельного вопроса. Так что задавайте новый, приводите пример кода, что нужно вытащить, что пытались делать, что получилось... А народ будет рад помочь разобраться...

Answer (score 1):

Ну выкачать страницы всё равно придётся, но ты же можешь сделать это сам программно, а не тащить весь сайт специальными программами. Просто обращаешься по нужным адресам, получаешь разметку страницы и сразу её парсишь. Можешь сохранять или не сохранять по необходимости.

А что касается защиты от роботов, можно же ещё забанить ip. Один из сайтов с обоями так делал при примрно 3 тысячах скачиваний. Решается легко - и используешь бесплатные прокси-серверы из нагугленного списка.

Comment: Можно подробнее, как можно выгрузить только интересующую меня директорию со страницами? Ссылки на документацию/примеры/может видео очень помогли бы.

Comment: @Bear, просто в цикле последовательно загружаешь страницы.